# Python - Write Header Once - Loop isn't working properly

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to write an "order file" with a Header and Detail Lines.  I am successfully getting the order Header to write to file, but only one detail line seems to get written to the file.

```
for k, v in atlantic_billing.iteritems():
    XHORNO = str(digits + counter)
    XHCSNO = k
    print XHCSNO
    machines = v
    line = 1
    counter = counter + 1
    header_written = False
    try :
        for machine in machines :
            XDORNO = XHORNO
            XDORSQ = line
            line = line + 1
            XDITD1 = ranpak_dict[machine]['MODEL']
            XDITD2 = ranpak_dict[machine]['SN']
            XDCAVC = ranpak_dict[machine]['TOTAL']
            print XDORSQ, XDITD1, XDITD2, XDCAVC
            if XDCAVC > 0 :
                if header_written == False :
                    with open(XHORNO + ".txt", 'w') as order:
                        order.write("H01, " + XHORNO + ", " + XHCSNO + "\n")
                        order.write("D01," + str(XDORSQ) + ", " + ' EQPRANUSER, ' + XDITD1 + ", " +  XDITD2 + ", " + XDCAVC + "\n")
                else :
                    order.write("D01," + str(XDORSQ) + ", " + ' EQPRANUSER, ' + XDITD1 + ", " +  XDITD2 + ", " + XDCAVC + "\n")
                    success.append(machine)
                    header_written = True

    except KeyError, e:
        issues.append(machine)
```

Comment: I think you want to do `with open(XHORNO +  ".txt", "w") as order:` before the start of the `for machine in machines:` loop. Also, I would put `header_written = True` in the `if header_written == False:` block.

Comment: @DavidCullen If I move the `with open (XHORNO + "txt", "a")` to before the `for machine in machines:` loop, it writes the file before I can validate that any of lines are billable?

Comment: It will create the file, but nothing will be written until you call `order.write`. This does not sound like the behavior your desire. However, putting `with open(XHORNO + ".txt", 'w') as order:` inside the `if` statement is almost certainly not the behavior your desire either, because `order` gets closed at the end of the `if` statement (before the `else` statement). Maybe you should collect the data for each machine in a list of lines and then write the list of lines after the `for machine in machines:` loop if the length of the list of lines is greater than zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When opening the file, you should use the mode `"A"` else the file will be overwritten at each loop (again and again):

```
 with open(XHORNO + ".txt", 'a') as order:
     ...
```

see https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

An other option is to take the `with`block over the for block.

Comment: That got me all my detail lines, thanks so much!  Now it is repeatedly @Antoine writing the heading level.  I am not sure that moving the with block over the for block will work, bc I am trying to only write files that have valid non-0 lines.  Any ideas on that dilemma?

Comment: Maybe use the len() function to check the length of the line before first  write. Then check the existence of the file before writing again with os.path.exists() (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists).

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the file only once and not inside the loop

```
for k, v in atlantic_billing.iteritems():
    XHORNO = str(digits + counter)
    with open(XHORNO + ".txt", 'w') as order: # <--- here you go
        XHCSNO = k
        print XHCSNO
        machines = v
        line = 1
        counter = counter + 1
        header_written = False
        try :
            for machine in machines :
                XDORNO = XHORNO
                XDORSQ = line
                line = line + 1
                XDITD1 = ranpak_dict[machine]['MODEL']
                XDITD2 = ranpak_dict[machine]['SN']
                XDCAVC = ranpak_dict[machine]['TOTAL']
                print XDORSQ, XDITD1, XDITD2, XDCAVC
                if XDCAVC > 0 :
                    if header_written == False :

                        order.write("H01, " + XHORNO + ", " + XHCSNO + "\n")
                        order.write("D01," + str(XDORSQ) + ", " + ' EQPRANUSER, ' + XDITD1 + ", " +  XDITD2 + ", " + XDCAVC + "\n")
                    else :
                        order.write("D01," + str(XDORSQ) + ", " + ' EQPRANUSER, ' + XDITD1 + ", " +  XDITD2 + ", " + XDCAVC + "\n")
                        success.append(machine)
                        header_written = True

        except KeyError, e:
            issues.append(machine)
```

Comment: I think you need to put the `with open(XHORNO + ".txt", 'w') as order:` before the `for machine in machines:` loop. XHORNO is a variable that changes inside the outer for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for k, v in atlantic_billing.iteritems():
    XHORNO = str(digits + counter)
    XHCSNO = k
    print XHCSNO
    machines = v
    line = 1
    counter = counter + 1
    header_written = False
    try :
        for machine in machines :
            XDORNO = XHORNO
            XDORSQ = line
            line = line + 1
            XDITD1 = ranpak_dict[machine]['MODEL']
            XDITD2 = ranpak_dict[machine]['SN']
            XDCAVC = ranpak_dict[machine]['TOTAL']
            print XDORSQ, XDITD1, XDITD2, XDCAVC
            if XDCAVC > 0 :
                with open(XHORNO + ".txt", 'a') as order:
                    if header_written == False :
                        order.write("H01, " + XHORNO + ", " + XHCSNO + "\n")
                        order.write("D01," + str(XDORSQ) + ", " + ' EQPRANUSER, ' + XDITD1 + ", " +  XDITD2 + ", " + XDCAVC + "\n")
                        header_written = True
                    else :
                        order.write("D01," + str(XDORSQ) + ", " + ' EQPRANUSER, ' + XDITD1 + ", " +  XDITD2 + ", " + XDCAVC + "\n")
                        success.append(machine)

    except KeyError, e:
        issues.append(machine)
```